# Error CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR in running HashCat 4.0.1

Tags: 14.04, hash

I've downloaded HashCat 4.0.1 form its official website. Running it show following error:

```
root@mstehr:~/hashcat-4.0.1# ./hashcat64.bin -I
hashcat (v4.0.1) starting...

clGetPlatformIDs(): CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I can run this command successfully on another Ubuntu box.

Result of `head /proc/cpuinfo`:

```
root@mstehr:~# head /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 58
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3210 CPU @ 3.20GHz
stepping        : 9
microcode       : 0x15
cpu MHz         : 3192.864
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
```

Result of ls `lspci`:

```
root@kmstehr:~# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Technology Express, Inc. Device 8892 (rev 41)
04:01.0 Ethernet controller: D-Link System Inc DGE-528T Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (rev 10)
```

Result of `ls /etc/OpenCL/vendors/`:

```
root@kmstehr:~# ls /etc/OpenCL/vendors/
ls: cannot access /etc/OpenCL/vendors/: No such file or directory
```

Comment: please add output of `lspci` and `ls /etc/OpenCL/vendors/` and `head /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: Do you have any graphic card?

Comment: @SuB: no i havn't

Comment: https://youtu.be/AieYqNQ6ADM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output of `lspci` indicates that the only graphic card on your system is `Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200` which is part of your *Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3210* processor. Also you haven't installed OpenCl library yet, so follow these steps:

Install lsb-core package using:

```
apt-get install lsb-core
```

Intel CPUs require OpenCL Runtime for Intel Core and Intel Xeon Processors (16.1.1 or later). Download and install `OpenCL™ Runtime 16.1.2 for Intel® Core™ and Intel® Xeon® Processors for Red Hat* and Ubuntu* Linux* (64-bit)` from [this page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#latest_CPU_runtime). Ignore the compatibility warning:

```
tar xf opencl_runtime_16.1.2_x64_rh_6.4.0.37.tgz
cd opencl_runtime_16.1.2_x64_rh_6.4.0.37
sudo ./install_GUI.sh
```

Comment: the download for "OpenCL™ Runtime 16.1.2 for Intel® Core™ and Intel® Xeon® Processors for Red Hat* and Ubuntu* Linux* (64-bit)" is broken. only up to 16.1.1 works.

Comment: https://youtu.be/AieYqNQ6ADM step by step tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error while creating a tutorial on how to install hashcat on Ubuntu 18.04; I've included the instructions below for Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors- feel free to review my [full gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/alexanderjsingleton/d00a56a51127e73b70a2cdffcd75c9e2).  Hope that helps!

### Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors

#### Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors - Option A (Recommended)

1. Check your CPU system processor architecture by running `sudo lscpu` to identify the class of CPU e.g. "Intel (R) Core (TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60Ghz"- alternatively, you can go to Settings > Details which will also reveal the CPU-family (e.g. Intel (R) HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2)).
2. Go to the [Intel Developer Zone](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#graph-lin-ubuntu) and scroll down to the corresponding download link for your system; assuming you're running Ubuntu 18.04 and have a Intel Core-class CPU, scroll down to "Linux* OS Ubuntu* 16.04.x (deb)" and click on the [Github link for 18.46.11837 Runtimes](https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases) to access the runtime-packages to download.
3. There should be instructions within the aforementioned Github repo- or you can proceed with the following in the next steps.
4. `cd ~/Desktop`
5. `mkdir neo`
6. `cd neo`
7. `sudo wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/18.46.11837/intel-gmmlib_18.4.0.348_amd64.deb`
8. `wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/18.46.11837/intel-igc-core_18.44.1060_amd64.deb`
9. `wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/18.46.11837/intel-igc-opencl_18.44.1060_amd64.deb`
10. `wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/18.46.11837/intel-opencl_18.46.11837_amd64.deb`
11. Install the packages by running `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.
12. Restart the system by running `sudo reboot`.

#### Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors - Option B

1. Go to [Intel OpenCL Runtimes website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers) and scroll down to the bottom of the page to Download Intel CPU Runtime for OpenCL Applications 18.1 for LINUX OS (64-bit only).
2. After downloading the OpenCL Runtimes for Intel Processors, `cd ~/Downloads`
3. Run `sudo tar -xzf l_opencl_p_18.1.0.013.tgz` to unpack the tgz file- please note, the OpenCL file version may update since the time as of this gist (ie as of this gist, the version is 18.1.0.013.)
4. `cd l_opencl_p_18.1.0.013`
5. Run `sudo ./install.sh`
6. A welcome screen is prompted- hold-down the "Enter" key until able to input select "2" for "I do NOT consent to the collection of my Information"
7. Hit "1"
8. Hit "1"
9. Hit "Enter" and then restart the computer.
10. If any additional Intel OpenCL errors are encountered after testing hashcat, go to section 'Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors - B'- if not, proceed with section "Testing Hashcat"