# Error CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR in running HashCat 5.1.0

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, ubuntu-drivers, opencl

Following up from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994142/error-cl-platform-not-found-khr-in-running-hashcat-4-0-1?newreg=aeb81c18991047e4810517e134ac58fc),

I have followed these instructions, including other resources. Here is the error:

```
dan@dans-ubuntu:~$ hashcat -I
hashcat (v5.1.0) starting...

clGetPlatformIDs(): CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR
```

Result of `head /proc/cpuinfo`:

```
head /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 165
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10900K CPU @ 3.70GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0xec
cpu MHz     : 2838.499
cache size  : 20480 KB
physical id : 0
```

Result of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b33 (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 06d2
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b8 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06bc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0685
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2206 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aef (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 15f3 (rev 02)
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
```

Result of `ls /etc/OpenCL/vendors/`:

```
intel.icd nvidia.icd
```

Attempts to resolve:

0. Following the answers from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994142/error-cl-platform-not-found-khr-in-running-hashcat-4-0-1?newreg=aeb81c18991047e4810517e134ac58fc)
1. Easy install with `apt install intel-opencl-icd`
2. Manual install found [here](https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue. While hashcat will not run on my intel integrated graphics, it will run on my GPU. I had to install the nVidia cuda development kit found
[here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). This solved everything.